# Inherit class instance attributes in the most right way

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a lot of books, divided into chapters, so I decided to create a simple class for `Book`. The class is below:

```py
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title:str  = None, type:str  = None, chapter:str  = None)
        self.title = title
        self.type = type
        self.chapter = chapter
```

The only changing variable on each book is the chapter name. And in my perfect [python](/questions/tagged/python) world, I'd like to create the first instance:

```py
book1 = Book("Title", "book", "Chapter one")
```

and then just clone instances and change its chapter attribute:

```py
book2 = book1
book2.chapter = "Chapter two"
```

But, it'll not work as the `book1.chapter` attribute is changing too.

So I have to do something like:

```py
from copy import copy
book2 = copy(book1)
book2.chapter = "Chapter two"
```

or

```py
book2 = Book()
book2.__dict__.update(book1.__dict__)
book2.chapter = "Chapter two"
```

I am a new programmer and I would like to know if these are the only ways to do this or I can make the code less clumsy & without imports?

Comment: Using `copy` or `deepcopy` is the easiest way and it definitely does not make your code clumsy.

Comment: You could do `book2 = Book(book1.title, book1.type, "Chapter two")`. But I think there's a logical flaw here: a `Book` should consist of _many_ chapters, not one. It's especially weird that you're copying `book1`'s title and type into _another_ `Book`: are these books... somehow part of the same book (because of the same title and type)?

Comment: book2 and book1 when you set them equal are pointing to the same address space in memory (the same object). When you call copy, you are creating a second instance of that object with its own address in memory (which is what you want). This way you can modify book2's object in its own memory space without bothering book1.

Comment: I agree with ForceBru, the naming of the class `Book` is very confusing if there are multiple `Book` objects associated with a single title of book.

Comment: @ForceBru In fact I have more complex books structure and each "chapter" is ~800 and more pages part, covering some fundamental topic, divided to subtopics. But for simplicity I wrote such example that show my main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) of the chapter titles, then [iterate](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp) through them as you create your books. You can use a list comprehension to write this succinctly:

```py
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title:str  = None, type:str  = None, chapter:str  = None):
        self.title = title
        self.type = type
        self.chapter = chapter

chapters = ["Chapter One", "Chapter Two", "Chapter Three"]

books = [Book("Title", "book", chapterName) for chapterName in chapters]
```

And if you need separate variables, that's doable, too:

```py
(book1, book2, book3) = (Book("Title", "book", chapterName) for chapterName in chapters)
```

Comment: I like this solution (with separate variables in tuple) as it doesn't use imports and doesn't need extra methods in class.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to create a proper interface to get a new book based on a previous one. In Python terms, you can write a `classmethod` that returns a new `Book` instance based on another instance:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title:str  = None, type:str  = None, chapter:str  = None):
        self.title = title
        self.type = type
        self.chapter = chapter
    
    @classmethod
    def from_other_book(cls, chapter, book):
        return cls(title=book.title, type=book.type, chapter=chapter)


book1 = Book("Title", "book", "Chapter one")
book2 = Book.from_other_book("Chapter two", book)
```

Edit: my answer addresses your question, although I agree with @ForceBru's comment in the OP - a new `Book` instance should not represent a new chapter of the same book.